# Balls and boxes. Average

Tags: probability, probability-theory, average

We have $r$ balls and $n$ boxes. We took all balls to boxes randomly. Find the average of empty boxes.

So I think there are two ways. When $r<n$ and $r\geq n$.

When $r<n$ thank can be $1,2,3,...,n-1$ boxes empty. Than average would be $\frac{\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}i}{n-1}$

When $r\geq n$ , then can be $0,1,2,...,n-1$ with average $\frac{\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}i}{n-1}$

And I don't know what to do next. To sum my given averages and divide from two? Or everything here is wrong? How to find the average than?

Comment: Almost everything here is wrong. It is not true that every time you can divide the possible outcomes of something into $n$ cases, every case must be equally likely as any other. It is true that if $r\geq n$ then all the cases $0,1,\ldots,n-1$ are possible, and if $r<n$ then $n-1$ is possible. But take $r=3,n=7,$ then you cannot have exactly $1$ box empty or even only $3$ boxes empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I preassume that "we took all balls to boxes randomly" can be interpreted as: for every ball the probability that it ends up in box $i$ is $\frac1n$.

For $i=1,\dots,n$ let $X_i$ take value $1$ if the box $i$ is empty after the placing, and let it take value $0$ otherwise.

Then $X=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is the number of empty boxes after placing the balls and with linearity of expectation and symmetry we find:$$\mathbb EX=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb EX_i=n\mathbb EX_1=nP(X_1=1)$$

So it remains to find $P(X_1=1)$.

Give that a try.

Comment: I you sure that we need to find $\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)$ not a $\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)$?

Comment: $P(X_i=1)=P(X_1=1)$ for every $i$, so there is no difference.

Comment: but what is  next? I can't figure out

Comment: Next? If you have found $P(X_1=1)$ then you are ready. The average you are looking for is $nP(X_1=1)$ as stated in my answer. Can you find $P(X_1=1)$?

Comment: No, I can't. I was thinking that $\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)$ means that all balls got to the first box or $n-1$ got to the first box or $n-2$ got to the first box and so on. But I don't know $n>r$ or not. So I don't know how to finish my sequence.

Comment: $X_1=1$ iff the first box stays empty. The probability on that is $\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^r$ (i.e. the probability that each of the $r$ balls is placed in one of the $n-1$ other boxes).